# API Misuse (Apple): Trying to free data which has not been allocated

Tags: objective-c, macos, static-analysis, keychain

[An app](http://hermesapp.org/) I'm working on works with simple password items in the Login Keychain. I noticed there is a `SecKeychainItemRef` that is never freed. The [official documentation on `SecKeychainFindGenericPassword()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_43) reads:

> On return, a pointer to the item object of the generic password. You are responsible for releasing your reference to this object.

After some quick changes, the static code analyzer claims:

1. Assuming 'result' is equal to noErr
2. Assuming 'item' is non-null
3. Trying to free data which has not been allocated

I'm at a loss at how I'm assuming result is equal to noErr as there is an else clause. Not quite sure where I am assuming item is non-null nor how I am freeing data that is not allocated since it's checked (`if (item)`).

## Screenshot of the warnings and code listing

[image: Screenshot of the warning and code listing]

## Code Listings

This is a [part of](https://github.com/HermesApp/Hermes/blob/master/Classes/Keychain.m#L12) the Hermes project on GitHub.

### Old

```
BOOL KeychainSetItem(NSString* username, NSString* password) {
  SecKeychainItemRef item;
  OSStatus result = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
    NULL,
    strlen(KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME),
    KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME,
    [username length],
    [username UTF8String],
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &item);

  if (result == noErr) {
    result = SecKeychainItemModifyContent(item, NULL, [password length],
                                          [password UTF8String]);
    return result == noErr;
  } else {
    result = SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(
      NULL,
      strlen(KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME),
      KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME,
      [username length],
      [username UTF8String],
      [password length],
      [password UTF8String],
      NULL);

    return result == noErr;
  }
}
```

### New

```
BOOL KeychainSetItem(NSString* username, NSString* password) {
  SecKeychainItemRef item = nil;
  OSStatus result = SecKeychainFindGenericPassword(
    NULL,
    strlen(KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME),
    KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME,
    [username length],
    [username UTF8String],
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &item);

  if (result == noErr) {
    result = SecKeychainItemModifyContent(item, NULL, [password length],
                                          [password UTF8String]);
  } else {
    result = SecKeychainAddGenericPassword(
      NULL,
      strlen(KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME),
      KEYCHAIN_SERVICE_NAME,
      [username length],
      [username UTF8String],
      [password length],
      [password UTF8String],
      NULL);
  }

  if (item) {
    SecKeychainItemFreeContent(NULL, item);
  }
  return result == noErr;
}
```

Comment: It's not *you* who is assuming that result == noErr. The Static analyzer is telling you which code path it took to reach the given error. If the result is noErr and item is not NULL, it thinks this is happening. Sadly, I don't offhand see why this would be an error, but I can't look up the docs right now to verify all params are the right order etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SecKeychainItemRef` variables are **CoreFoundation reference counted**. From the static code analyzer's point of view, calling `SecKeychainItemFreeContent()` on a `SecKeychainItemRef` amounts to freeing unallocated data since it was not allocated by the SecKeychain functions.

All the errors went away by calling `CFRelease()` on the `SecKeychainItemRef` variable (instead of `SecKeychainItemFreeContent()`).